# zip folder's and take the name of folder

Tags: python, list, zip

I'm trying to make this code which take the content of each folder in directory and add it to zip one by one with the name of folder

I did made this code but I'm blocked with just add file by extension in zip

```
import zipfile, os

handle = zipfile.ZipFile('ALL-PY.zip', 'w')

for x in os.listdir():
    if x.endswith(directory):
         handle.write(x,compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

handle.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this approach:

```
import zipfile, os

handle = zipfile.ZipFile('ALL-PY.zip', 'w')

path = "C:/Users/User_Name/my_directory" # This is YOUR INPUT - set with the directory you want to zip

os.chdir(path)

for directory, subs, files in os.walk("."):
    handle.write(directory)
    for this_file in files:
        handle.write(os.path.join(directory, this_file), compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

handle.close()
```

Comment: error in this line path = "C:/Users/User_Name/my_directory"
can't decode bytes position

Comment: @FonasTahor `path` is the directory whose content (files and subdirectories) you want to zip.